# Methods must be security critical or security safe-critical to satisfy a LinkDemand

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using .net framework 4.6.2 and We have created one **httpmodule** for our application.

The .Net trust level for application is set to **Medium**. We can not change the .net trust level as we have to make our application compatible with medium trust level and also we can not remove LinkDemand SecurityAction from class level attribute because if we remove **LinkDemand** then **AntiHttpCrossSiteForgeryRequestSettings** class throws exception because of partial trust level.

We are getting below error -

> Attempt by security transparent method 'Framework.HttpModule.AntiHttpCrossSiteForgeryRequestModule.Init(System.Web.HttpApplication)' to access LinkDemand protected method 'Framework.HttpModule.AntiHttpCrossSiteForgeryRequestModule.PreSendRequestHeaders(System.Object, System.EventArgs)' failed.  Methods must be security critical or security safe-critical to satisfy a LinkDemand.

Code:

```
namespace Framework.HttpModule
{
    [AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
    [AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
    public class AntiHttpCrossSiteForgeryRequestModule : IHttpModule
    {

        private const string ContextIndexName = "AntiHttpCrossSiteForgeryRequestModule.CSRFToken";


        [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreSendRequestHeaders += PreSendRequestHeaders;
            context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += PreRequestHandlerExecute;
            context.AcquireRequestState += AcquireRequestStateExecute;
        }

        private static void PreRequestHandlerExecute(object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
            HttpContext context = application.Context;
            HttpCookie HttpModuleCSRFCookie = context.Request.Cookies[AntiHttpCrossSiteForgeryRequestSettings.Settings.AntiCSRFCookie];
        }
        private static void AcquireRequestStateExecute(object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
        }
        private static void PreSendRequestHeaders(object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {

        }
    }

    public sealed class AntiHttpCrossSiteForgeryRequestSettings : ConfigurationSection
    {

        private const string AntiCSRFCookieNameKey = "antiCSRFC";
        private const string AntiCSRFFormFieldKey = "antiCSRFF";


        ////The default value for configuration attribute
        private const string AntiCSRFCookieDefaultValue = "ANTICSRFC";
        private const string AntiCSRFFormFieldDefaultValue = "ANTICSRFT";


        //The CSRF settings.
        private static AntiHttpCrossSiteForgeryRequestSettings settings =
            ConfigurationManager.GetSection("AntiHttpCrossSiteForgeryRequestSettings") as AntiHttpCrossSiteForgeryRequestSettings;


        //Gets the CSRF Settings.
        public static AntiHttpCrossSiteForgeryRequestSettings Settings
        {
            get
            {
                // If the configuration setting is not present create one with the default values.
                if (settings == null)
                {
                    settings = new AntiHttpCrossSiteForgeryRequestSettings
                    {
                        AntiCSRFCookie = AntiCSRFCookieDefaultValue,
                        AntiCSRFFormField = AntiCSRFFormFieldDefaultValue,
                    };
                }

                return settings;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty(AntiCSRFCookieNameKey, DefaultValue = AntiCSRFCookieDefaultValue)]
        public string AntiCSRFCookie
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base[AntiCSRFCookieNameKey];
            }

            set
            {
                base[AntiCSRFCookieNameKey] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty(AntiCSRFFormFieldKey, DefaultValue = AntiCSRFFormFieldDefaultValue)]
        public string AntiCSRFFormField
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base[AntiCSRFFormFieldKey];
            }

            set
            {
                base[AntiCSRFFormFieldKey] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```